Error during connect: Post "http://docker:2375/v1.24/auth": dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.30.0.2:53: no such host
I just created a simple gitlab-ci.yml file to create Docker environment within the CI/CD pipeline. What confuses me is the error
http://docker:2375/v1.24/auth": dial tcp: lookup docker on 172.30.0.2:53: no such host
I tried using DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "" and different docker and docker:dind versions. Didn't fix the problem. Is this expected or am I doing something wrong here?
default:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
      alias: thedockerhost

before_script:
  - docker info

stages:
  - build

variables:
  DOCKER_HOST: tcp://thedockerhost:2375
  DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "Building and tagging Docker images..."



Try this. Unless there's a compelling reason otherwise I'd suggest not setting DOCKER_HOST, DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR or DOCKER_DRIVER.
default:
  image: docker:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:dind

stages:
  - build

variables:
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG

build:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker info
  script:
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_TAG .


No luck. Still same error. I actually followed this https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/27300

Please add screenshot of the build process in GitLab. I don't see how you could be getting the same error since you are no longer specifying DOCKER_HOST...

I just added a screenshot to the original question. Maybe my runner is mixed up.

Perhaps. Are you using a self-hosted runner? If so then might be worthwhile looking at these blog posts: https://datawookie.dev/blog/2023/05/install-gitlab-runner-with-docker-update/ and https://datawookie.dev/blog/2021/03/install-gitlab-runner-with-docker/. Since you are using Docker-in-Docker you'll need to launch with the --docker-privileged flag.

Mate, you are a legend. I used privileged runners and tagged them to gitlab yml. Fixed it.
